# C# Crash on x64

Tags: c#, dll, 64-bit

I have a DLL created in VS 2008 and written in C#.
The dll project builds with the "Any CPU" flag.

When it is deployed and run on a Dell/Intel Windows 7 x64 machine it starts up OK, but it crashes when it tries to start using cryptography -- TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();

This is part of the mscorlib.dll.

I've built the app as targeting x64, but it also crashes in the same place.  It runs fine on 32 bit machines.

How can I get this to run successfully on x64?

Comment: What's the error message/exception?

Comment: Does it run on the x64 machine if you build it for x86? If so, they something isn't 64-bit ready.

Comment: There is no error.  The app that calls into it crashes and there is a popup about sending the dump to microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problem with windows services created in .NET. It was throwing exception and the Windows log file indicated errors in mscorlib.dll and kernel32.dll (if I remember correctly). No external 32 bits dll or special codes was used, only plain .NET.

The solution I got is to compile as x86 and then run it (as 32 bits) application on the 64 bits machine. This could be a solution as long as you don't need 64bits to run your app.

Answer (score 1):

> The solution I got is to compile as x86 and then run it (as 32 bits)
>   application on the 64 bits machine. This could be a solution as long
>   as you don't need 64bits to run your app. - Gaël Mo

I'd just like to point out that compiling and running for x86 on a 64 bit machine is ***NOT*** an answer... Joe would like to know why its crashing in x64 mode... obviously running in x86 mode works on x64 machines. If you couldn't get your car to run with a certain after-market part, would you consider it a valid answer if I told you to simply run the car without the part in it? Obviously not... Think carefully about your answers before posting them ok?

> Does it run on the x64 machine if you build it for x86? If so, they
>   something isn't 64-bit ready. – sgmoore

I agree... I'd like to add that if you do not have the source code (you probably don't) then you are out of luck I'm afraid... I found [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx#64mig_topic4) article that explains more fully... Apart from that, you may need to look into a different DES decryption library... OpenSSL/SSH perhaps?